# Syntax error with system() command to rename a file in C

Tags: c, windows-8.1

I'm trying to rename a file through a system() command and I get (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

This is the line from my code:
system("ren" "C:\Users\Mac\Desktop\new folder\03 Elfsong - Shar.mp3 test.mp3");

What is the syntax problem here?

Comment: Don't do this. Use the `rename` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was escape sequence,

The syntax is:
system ("ren old_filename new_filename");

But you must use escape sequence because of the white spaces in the name of the file, and for the '\' in the path since only a white space separate between old filename and the new filename.

And also you must contain the old filename in (\"\") to specify it as (old_filename) in the syntax.

Code:

system("ren \"C:\Users\Mac\Desktop\New folder\03 Elfsong - Shar.mp3\" \"test.mp3\"");

Answer (score 0):

`ren` is a cmd.exe built-in command, it's not a standalone executable, so you'd have to do

```
system("CMD", "/c ren originalname newname");
```

Comment: _And_ you may need to put " quotes around the individual names since they contain blanks, _and_ you may have the double the backslashes to `\\` so they won't be misinterpreted as escape sequences.

Comment: The answer was escape sequence.   

Code:
system("ren \"C:\Users\Mac\Desktop\New folder\03 Elfsong - Shar.mp3\" \"test.mp3\"");